# How to allow empty field to be submit when field is not mandatory

Tags: jquery, regex

I have a regular expression for "media_topic" it should allow characters and space and also it should allow empty data because it is not mandatory field. When I submit without entering anything means it should to allow submit but it is happening.

Below is my code,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.validator.addMethod('media_topic', function(value, element) {
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9,_-\\s]*$");
    var key = value;

    if (!regex.test(key)) {
    return false;
    }
    return true;
}, "Please valid media topic.");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using an alternation in your regex which allows for no input:

```
var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9,_\\s-]*|$");
```

The basic idea is:

```
^(some pattern)|$
```

## Demo

Comment: @Mohan Your original regex has other problems.  Check the demo and you will see that my pattern accepts empty input.

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
 ignore: ".ignore"
```

When field is empty add class .ignore to it
if not empty then remove that class

Hope this Helps.

Comment: Where to add that class?

Comment: to html element

Comment: <input type = 'text' class='ignore'> like this,

Answer (score 0):

May be it is better to check first if your value is empty before performing regex.

e.g.
`if (value == "") {return True;}`